# Insert rows based on number of distinct values in another table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with PO#,Days_to_travel, and Days_warehouse fields. I take the distinct Days_in_warehouse values in the table and insert them into a temp table. I want a script that will insert all of the values in the Days_in_warehouse field from the temp table into the Days_in_warehouse_batch row in table 1 by PO# duplicating the PO records until all of the POs have a record per distinct value.
Example:
Temp table: (Contains only one field with all distinct values in table 1)

```
Days_in_warehouse  
      20
      30
      40
```

Table 1 :

```
PO#  Days_to_travel Days_in_warehouse  Days_in_warehouse_batch
1        10              20             
2         5              30
3         7              40
```

Updated Table 1:

```
PO#  Days_to_travel Days_in_warehouse  Days_in_warehouse_batch
1        10              20                    20
1        10              20                    30
1        10              20                    40
2         5              30                    20
2         5              30                    30
2         5              30                    40
3         7              40                    20
3         7              40                    30
3         7              40                    40
```

Any ideas as to how can I update Table 1 to see desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more way without a TEMP table and DELETE.

```
UPDATE T SET [Days_in_warehouse_batch] = [Days_in_warehouse];

INSERT INTO T ([PO], [Days_to_travel], 
               [Days_in_warehouse], [Days_in_warehouse_batch]) 
    SELECT T.PO, 
           T.Days_to_travel,
           T.Days_in_warehouse,
           DAYS_Table.Days_in_warehouse
    FROM T
    CROSS JOIN 
          (SELECT DISTINCT Days_in_warehouse FROM T) as DAYS_Table
    WHERE T.Days_in_warehouse <> DAYS_Table.Days_in_warehouse;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9f511/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `cartesian product` between your two tables.

```
select t1.po, t1.daystotravel, t1.daysinwarehouse, temp.daysinwarehousebatch
from table1 t1, temp
```

The easiest way I can think of updating table1 with these values is to insert them, and then delete the originals.

```
insert into table1     
select t1.po, t1.daystotravel, t1.daysinwarehouse, temp.daysinwarehousebatch
from table1 t1, temp
```

And then delete the originals:

```
delete from table1 where daysinwarehousebatch is null
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca254/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
insert into table1(PO#, Days_to_travel, Days_in_warehouse, Days_in_warehouse_batch)
    select PO#, Days_to_travel, Days_in_warehouse, Days_in_warehouse
    from table1 cross join
         (select 20 as Days_in_warehouse union all select 30 union all select 40) var
    where Days_in_warehouse_batch is null;

delete from table1
    where Days_in_warehouse_batch is null;
```